# how to make Collision Markers visible in rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

according to this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Tutorial%20A), i can successfully check the state validity. but i don't know what i should do to make the collision markers visible in rviz? do i need to manually publish a topic on the collision markers? i thought the /planning_scene_validity_server should do this job. i've already added "Marker" in rviz, but don't know which topic it should listen to.

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47178/how-to-make-collision-markers-visible-in-rviz?/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, just find this method in collision_models.h:

```
void getAllCollisionPointMarkers(const planning_models::KinematicState& state,
                                   visualization_msgs::MarkerArray& arr,
                                   const std_msgs::ColorRGBA& color,
                                   const ros::Duration& lifetime);
```

and now i can visualize these markers by manually publish them myself.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0